# MongoDB Cluster and 100,000 Capped Collections

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

How does a MongoDB cluster distribute Capped Collections across nodes for balancing load? I am planning to use a Capped Collection for comments of each Post in a MongoDB based CMS. Lets assume we have 100,000 Posts and hence 100,000 Capped Collections storing comments for each post. Will these Capped Collections be distributed evenly across cluster for read and write scalability?

I dont want to shard a capped collection. I want to distribute all the capped collections evenly across the cluster for read and write scalability.

Lets assume we have 5 machines. When we create new collections, I need them to be created on different machines/nodes and also redistribute them when new machines are added.

Comment: Looks like MongoDB does support a huge number of collections with a performance penalty and they are not automatically distributed across the cluster.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

Comment: The feature to automatically distribute collections across a cluster is in the pipeline on Dev List.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When creating a collection (capped or not) it is set on the primary shard of the database. The solution would be to set a collection per database so that mongo equilibrate the databases across ythe cluster. The rule for equilibrium is not clear but depends mainly on the current load on each  shard.

2) Believe me, you should use one big collection for all your post and shard it in a clever way. It will ensure really efficient and automatic balance of your data across your cluster.
More over capped collection are not really space efficient because it will pre-allocate all the space for all your collections (meaning that you'll have a lot of wasted space for nothing)
Unless you have a very good reason to go for capping, you have better try sharding.

One advice : use the 'postId' field in your shard key, it will probably the most performance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not implemented yet for mongodb: [Issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2654)

Quote from [similar question](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3230):

> But you can create multiple capped collections on different shards to
>   increase write throughput; however, you must then run multiple queries
>   to access all your data.

Comment: I dont want to shard a capped collection. I want to distribute all the capped collections evenly across the cluster for read and write scalability.